# Unable to remove ValueError for bad values [Closed: Resolved the issue]

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have generated features out of my data, to input into a learning algorithm.

I worked with a lot of features before but never encounter the problem of **valueError:** before on the same dataset.

Error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

structure of my data(features) is as follows:

```
p_s,ne_s,ng_s,su_s,val
90,2320,30,0
```

### This was the issue. total labels are 5 but values are 4

on doing this:

```
print(np.where(np.isnan(X)))
```

I get:

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
```

I also tried:

```
np.isnan(X)

np.nan_to_num(X)

pd.DataFrame(X).fillna()
```

But nothing worked for me!

---

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

X = data[['p_s','ne_s','ng_s','su_s']]

y = data['val']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
```

After this, I start fitting my data into algorithm.

```
---//some code//--
.fit(X_train, y_train)
---//some code//--
```

Expectations:

No value error. Also, why is this coming in the first place? I did a lot fo work with using upto seven features and never encountered the same. Moreover, I cannot be doing anything wrong in the code because there is no divide and multiplication in whole scenario.

Acutal:

ValueError: As stated above.

**Identified Issue:**

When I print **y_train** and **y_test** they return NaN values. So, I hope the data is correct.

Comment: Put a `try` block!

Comment: where? I m directly passing training data to fit() and testing with test data. Also, I did add ( try ) while storing the output of the algorithm into a list but still same error.

Comment: using `try` during `model.fit()` is not suggested, instead check my approach that I have posted below.

Comment: Also cannot find any NaN in my dataset manually.

Comment: Could you provide more details? It seems like the problem is not in the data, but rather with some other parameters. What line/function is throwing the execption? Can you put a breakpoint on the respective line? does this occur in the first iteration or after a while?

Comment: @Ido_f  you're right the problem is in y_train and y_test.

Comment: Alright, but all the nan tests above were done on X right? Did you try them on Y?

Comment: I cannot. all the y_train and y_test are NaN. doing that won't make any sense. Also, why does it have NaN when data doesn't have NaN in first place. Is there a issue with train_test_split ?

Comment: Done! I got it. There is some issue with the data itself. Now resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, never really used that function before. Try diving in it with the debugger. The function is native python so it shouldn't be a problem
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2073

Comment: Which model are you trying to fit the data? If all your target-values are NaN, I hope it is categorical. And if it is categorical, try translate them into numbers. I.e blue->0, red->1 etc.